# How to clone a record (server side) in Dynamics crm 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, cloning

I am using crm **2016** and I need to clone a record using plugin, after googling I found out that I need to use `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` that hold the `clone()` function - which is not in 2016 SDK because of MS reorganization.This lib is in 2015 SDK.
My questions are :
1. If I'll take that lib from CRM 2015 and use it in 2016 will it be supported?
2. If it's not supported what are my options to clone a record in server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Clone()` in the `Microsoft.Xrm.Client` only creates a copy of the `Entity` object in memory. It does not create a copy in the database of CRM. When you need to create a copy in the database just instantiate a new `Entity` object and pass it to the `Create()` method of the `IOrganizationService` interface.

When you really need a deep clone as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg678489(v=crm.7).aspx) you could consider writing one yourself. In most scenarios you will only need to copy the objects in the attributes collection. Of those objects only the reference types `EntityReference`, `OptionSetValue` and `Money` wiil need your special attention.

I would not advise to use deprecated libraries.

Answer (score 2):

We use the following helper method to clone an entity - this is an updated version from the original which correctly clones the reference types, and excludes the system attributes

```
public static Entity CloneEntitySandbox(Entity entityToClone)
    {
        var newEntity = new Entity(entityToClone.LogicalName);

        var systemAttributes = new List<string>();
        systemAttributes.Add("createdon");
        systemAttributes.Add("createdby");
        systemAttributes.Add("modifiedon");
        systemAttributes.Add("modifiedby");
        systemAttributes.Add("owninguser");
        systemAttributes.Add("owningbusinessunit");


        foreach (var attribute in entityToClone.Attributes
            .Where(x => x.Key != entityToClone.LogicalName + "id")
            .Where(x => !systemAttributes.Contains(x.Key))) 
        {

            switch (attribute.Value.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "Money":
                    var m = attribute.Value as Money;
                    newEntity[attribute.Key] = new Money(m.Value);
                    break;
                case "EntityReference":
                    var er = attribute.Value as EntityReference;
                    newEntity[attribute.Key] = new EntityReference(er.LogicalName, er.Id);
                    break;
                case "OptionSetValue":
                    var os = attribute.Value as OptionSetValue;
                    newEntity[attribute.Key] = new OptionSetValue(os.Value);
                    break;
                default:
                    newEntity[attribute.Key] = attribute.Value;
                    break;
            }

        }

        return newEntity;
    }
```

Note that this does not perform the save to create the cloned entity in the CRM database, that's up to you.

Comment: In your example the reference types `EntityReference`, `OptionSetValue` and `Money` are not cloned. Only the references to these objects are copied.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen Admittedly, yes the fields which are reference types do end up pointing to the value on the original entity - however when the cloned entity is saved to the database you do end up with a fresh copy of the original entity as expected

Comment: And when the cloned entity is saved twice to the database you end up with two fresh copies of the original entity, LoL!

Comment: Why not just do `newEntity.Attributes.Add(attribute)` in a loop where `attribute` is each property of `srcEntity.Attributes` ?

Comment: @DonCheadle because then you end up with both your original and cloned entity having references to the same attributes - changing the value of an attribute will effectively change it on both entities.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft announcement says:

> We also removed Microsoft.Xrm.Client from the CRM 2016 (8.x) SDK client because it was not compliant with the OAuth changes, and replaced it with Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector. You can use the current Microsoft Dynamics 365 Software Development Kit (SDK) to access Microsoft Dynamics CRM back to version 6.x for both auth and messaging.

[Dynamics 365 SDK Backwards Compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility/)

You can still use Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll in your project from older SDK, this maybe supported for a while.

But I would recommend to go with custom Action, taking parent record as EntityReference Input parameter, Retrieve the parent record data + needed related entities & manually create (clone) child record + related entities records in Action.

You can Execute/invoke this [Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45829714/7920473) from client/server side, wherever you want.